# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException converting C# to Java

Tags: java, c#, arraylist

I'm working on a program that will go through a list of records (IDs and Tickets) and parse them into two list respectively. It will also cross search the lists to see which IDs have a corresponding ticket based on names. Here is a link to an earlier version: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451831/write-to-file-java-vector)
Now, I've been rewritting with the help of some C# code from a coworker, but I'm having trouble with a parsing method. Here is the C# version:

```
        public void parseLine(string _line)
    {
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_line)){ return;}

        code        = _line.Substring(0, 3);
        ticketID    = _line.Substring(3, 10);

        string tmp = _line.Substring(13).Trim();

        //get the first and last name
        string [] tmp1 = tmp.Split(",".ToCharArray());

        if(!(tmp1.Length > 1))
        {
            throw new Exception("unable to get the first and last name");
        }

        lastname        = tmp1[0];
        firstname       = tmp1[1].Trim();

    }
```

Here is my Java version:

```
    public void parseLine(String line) throws Exception {
            // code will store Ticket code *Alpha ticketId will store 10
            // *digit code
    code = line.substring(0, 3);
    ticketId = line.substring(3, 10);
    
            // tmp will store everything afterthe first 13 characters of 
            // line and trim the name(s)
    String tmp = line.substring(13).trim();
    
            // tmp1 array
    String[] tmp1 = tmp.split(".*,.*");
    
    if (tmp1.length > 1) {
        
        throw new Exception("UNABLE TO GET NAME");
        
    }
    
    last = tmp1[0];
    first = tmp1[1].trim();
}
```

This is in a seperate class, that will model the people with tickets. My main class(so far) which invokes the actual parseLine method is as follows:

```
public class ParkingTickets {

public static void main(String[] args) throws 
        FileNotFoundException, Exception {

ArrayList<TicketPeople> tickets = new ArrayList<>();
HashMap<String, List<SbPeople>> people = new HashMap<>();
File srcFile = new File("source.txt");

Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(srcFile);
    
    while (myScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = myScanner.nextLine();
    //System.out.println(line);
    if (line.matches("^\\p{Alpha}.*$")) {
    //System.out.printf("Ticket: %s%n", line);
        TicketPeople t = new TicketPeople();
        t.parseLine(line);
        tickets.add(t);
        }
        myScanner.close();
    }

}
```

}

the compiler points at the if statement in the parseLine method, and obviously the parseLine method in main class, when I tried stepping through that sepcifiv line, I see that it's starts parsing the the data from the source file but something is off. From the documentation the error means: Thrown to indicate that an array has been accessed with an illegal index. The index is either negative or greater than or equal to the size of the array.
I used an ArrayList for the ticket list and from what I understand it is a dynamic list that does not need to be set with a specific index size. I'm still learning and am having trouble understanding this exception. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) In C# it is Substring(int startIndex, int length). In java String substring(int startindex, int endindex).

2)The java code has also changed the exception logic. In C# code ther eis a not if(!(tmp1.Length > 1)), whereas in java code, if (tmp1.length > 1)

Comment: #2 is one reason to avoid using `!` when there is a simple way to negate the condition.  The C# version should have been written `if (temp1.Length <= 1)`, and then it would have been a lot harder to make that mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `split()` in Java, doesn't match the `split()` from C#.

```
// String[] tmp1 = tmp.split(".*,.*");
String[] tmp1 = tmp.split(","); // <-- ",".
```

also, your check logic seems to have been reversed. But, I would suggest

```
if (tmp1.length != 2) {
    throw new Exception("UNABLE TO GET NAME");
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to remember why I had changed split() in my Java code. I guess I was trying to write a regex stating anything before or after "," delimiter. And my logic for the condition was definitely off, it should of stated if tmp1 is less than or equal to 1...correct? My question would then be, if i use (tmp1.length != 2) would that be a better a more accurate/effective condition?

Comment: @Luis I think so. You want two (and only two elements).